# Building stuff for android

Tags: android

I want to build some libraries into executables that I need to use with my application. For example I need to build the C library slocate, so that I can use it in my application. Another example, I have to build sqlite-3.1 db to be usable with Python from ASE.

How can I go about achieving that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build them using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/sdk/ndk/index.html).  After you build them into *.so files you can use them in your native code and access that through [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/).  It's not as hard as it sounds but it takes a good bit of setup.

Comment: I have a follow-up question about this. I want to build my own python as I am writing a python application which will run under ASE. Any insight if this will work?

Comment: I was able to embed Lua into an app that I was working on, so it should!  You just need to build the native code and create a JNI wrapper to give you access to all of the native functions from Java.